# Can one App service support both mobile and website?

Tags: azure, mobile

Can I use one azure mobile app as a backend to support for mobile app and website?

I need it to support push notification and authentication as well as CRUD operation.  Should I use API app or Mobile app or something else?

Answer (score 0):

An Azure Mobile App is just a regular [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) app with the [Azure Mobile Apps SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-mobile-apps) implemented.  Here is a good example of a combined web + mobile:

https://github.com/adrianhall/azure-mobile-apps-html-quickstart

The 'public' directory contains the static website, complete with JS and CSS files.  The app.js is your app (note the [serve-static module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static) usage to serve up the static content).

Answer (score 0):

Now that Mobile App, Web App, and API App are under one roof so to speak you have several options.

They are all part of App Services.

The easiest way to think about App Services is in terms of a VM that hosts multiple web apps in isolation.

You create an App Service that is *like* a VM and then you create multiple apps that run in that VM.

You could create a Mobile App and a completely separate Web App that share a common database for instance.

You pay for the App Service instance, not each app, so it's really up to you how you want to divide up the functionality.

Now before someone cries foul on my VM analogy, I said it was the *easiest* way to visualize it, not the most accurate.

What you really get is a "Virtual Virtual-Machine" that could be one or many VMs. You see it as one logical thing in terms of management, deployment, etc. but it could really be multiple VMs. It can scale up or down based on your configured options (eg 1 VM always, scale up to 5 VMs if CPU or Memory exceed thresholds you set, etc.).